# Magento 1.9 get product media tohtml

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to display media or image box inside another phtml. I am using this code but the getchildhtml() return nothing.

```
$block = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view');
$block->setProduct($_product); //$_product is the product object
$blockMedia = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view_media');
$block->setChild('media',$blockMedia);
echo $block->getChildHtml('media');
```

May be because the media is the child block of `catalog/product_view`.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to display media box to another phtml file.

```
$media_html = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product_view_media")->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate("catalog/product/view/media.phtml")->toHtml();
echo $media_html;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the content of what you need in this path:

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{your theme}/template/custom/media.phtml`

2. declare this block in xml:

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{your theme}/layout/local.xml`

```
<your_layout_handle>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="custom.media" template="custom/media.phtml" />
    </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

3. you past this code in the page where you want to display info stored in `media.phtml`

`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('custom.media'); ?>`

**Or**

you can skip the step 2 and replace the code of step3 with:

`<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('custom/media.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>`